# Injecting/embedding/adding/writing metadata to a .mp4 file so it's recognised as 360

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, metadata

I'm working on a library that injects/embeds/writes metadata into a `.mp4` file to allow the video to be displayed correctly as a 360 video. The input file is a standard `.mp4` file in the equirectangular format which I need to inject the proper metadata to get it to display as a 360 video. I know tools like Google's [Spatial Media Tool](https://github.com/google/spatial-media) exist but if possible I would like to do it with FFmpeg.

The metadata injected by the Spatial Media tool looks like this and is what I am trying to achieve:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><rdf:SphericalVideo
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:GSpherical="http://ns.google.com/videos/1.0/spherical/"><GSpherical:Spherical>true</GSpherical:Spherical><GSpherical:Stitched>true</GSpherical:Stitched><GSpherical:StitchingSoftware>Spherical Metadata Tool</GSpherical:StitchingSoftware><GSpherical:ProjectionType>equirectangular</GSpherical:ProjectionType></rdf:SphericalVideo>
```

These are all the things I have tried which did not work:

### Method 1

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -movflags use_metadata_tags -metadata Spherical=true -metadata Stitched=true -metadata ProjectionType=equirectangular -metadata StitchingSoftware=StreetviewJourney -codec copy output.mp4
```

I have tried many variations of it like adding `GSpherical:` and `xmp:` to the metadata tag.

### Method 2

When I extract the metadata using ffmpeg it contains the spherical tag in the logs but not when I output it to a ffmetadata file. This was the command I used: `ffmpeg -i injected.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -f ffmetadata data.txt`

This is the output of the log:

```
 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Side data:
      spherical: equirectangular (0.000000/0.000000/0.000000)
```

### Method 3

I also tried to get the metadata using this command: `ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_streams -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 injected.mp4`

This was the logs it outputted:

```
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
side_data_type=Spherical Mapping
projection=equirectangular
yaw=0
pitch=0
roll=0
```

I then tried to use this command but it didn't work:

```
ffmpeg -i chapmanspeak.mp4 -movflags use_metadata_tags -metadata side_metadata_type="Spherical Mapping" -metadata projection=equirectangular -metadata yaw=0 -metadata pitch=0 -metadata roll=0 -codec copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

*Metadata* is not the same as *frame side data.* FFmpeg tool currently cannot do this, you need to program own thing using available API.

Comment: What C# API  can do this?

Comment: FFmpeg is written in C, not C#.

Comment: Of course but you can use FFmpeg in almost any language with a wrapper. But that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Something like this, but note that that may not be really enough at all as relevant stuff in muxer is not implemented by FFmpeg at all: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.3/group__lavu__video__spherical.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this if you just want to transcode instead of writing metadata freshly into the file

```
sudo ffmpeg -i 360video.MP4 -vcodec libx264 -strict unofficial -vprofile high  -acodec aac -f mp4  another.mp4
```

Comment: there is no reason to use `sudo` here.